# Camel route on filename prefix

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

I have some file with Extentions

```
DOA01022016.txt [which is date of admission]
PROFILE01022016.txt [which is student profile] &
RESULTS01022016.txt [which is students results]

So naming convention is PREFIXDDMMYYY.txt

from uri="sftp://10.10.101.10/tmp/admin/?username=admin&amp;password=admin123"
```

Using camel I am trying with `when --> choice --> simple --> contains --> Headers` approach.

Somehow its not good approach of doing it. 
I also tried following [Camel File](http://camel.apache.org/file.html)

Any other better way using camel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of content based routing, you should just use ant pattern include parameter in your FTP route definitions:

```
from("sftp://10.10.101.10/tmp/admin/?username=admin&password=admin123&antInclude=**/DOA*.txt")
    .log("date of admission ${body}");

from("sftp://10.10.101.10/tmp/admin/?username=admin&password=admin123&antInclude=**/PROFILE*.txt")
    .log("student profile ${body}");

from("sftp://10.10.101.10/tmp/admin/?username=admin&password=admin123&antInclude=**/RESULTS*.txt")
    .log("results ${body}");
```